# How to reach a webserver via fargate?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, clojure

I have created a webpage with clojure and it works perfectly on ec2 on port 8555 with ssl. It also works in the docker container in the same ec2 machine.

It does not work in a fargate container in front of an nlb. I have my dns on the load balancer. The private ip of the running container is also healthy and the security group has an inbound rule for 8555

If i invoke the site: https://www.doppelkopf.me:8555
Secure Connection Failed

```
An error occurred during a connection to www.doppelkopf.me:8555. SSL peer was unable to negotiate an acceptable set of security parameters.
```

**Error code: SSL_ERROR_HANDSHAKE_FAILURE_ALERT
The page you are trying to view cannot be shown because the authenticity of the received data could not be verified.
Please contact the website owners to inform them of this problem.**

If i invoke without ssl, i get at least an encrypted hello world:
http://www.doppelkopf.me:8555

Does ssl need to initiate a connection as well? Do i maybe need nat-gateway? My certicate is in my container.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know why, but this suddenly worked, when i changed the port from 8555 to 443 with ssl.